# Leaflet - problem with groupedLayerControl plugin

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I would like to implement the [GroupedLayerControl](https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol) plugin to my leaflet map.

Unfortunately, after applying the `L.control` it stops working.

My layers look as this:

```
 var maptiles = {
"OpenStreetMap": osm,
"Hybrid": hybridMutant
};


 var overlays = {
  "Eclipses" :{
    "Annular" : annular,
    "Hybrid" : hybrid,
    "Total" : total
  },
  "Places" : {
      "Places": places
  }
 };
```

I've tried:

```
 var layers = L.control.groupedLayers(maptiles, overlays);
 map.addControl(layers);
```

and

```
 L.control.layers(maptiles, overlays).addTo(map);
```

neither first nor second example was working. After this code, the map is crashed and I see only the OpenStreetMap canvas and everything, which is above this line of code.

I've checked the console, which for the first case says:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_leaflet_id' of undefined**

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1074
https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-panel-layers/issues/6

and for the second one:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'minZoom' of undefined**

discussed also here:

[L.control.layers: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'minZoom' of undefined](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302395/l-control-layers-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-minzoom-of-undefine)

Is there something wrong with my layers? I've defined variables, which include a bunch of separate .geojson layers.

Full JSfiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/okezw4dL/

It starts working, when the grouped `L.GeoJSON` layers are switched off.
The one example of this group is below.

```
var hybrid = L.geoJSON([H23, H31, H49, H50, H67], {
 style: function (feature) {
   return {
    fillColor: '#0000FF',
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 0.5,
    color: 'blue',
    fillOpacity: 0.25
   };
  },
  coordsToLatLng: function (coords) {
  var latLng = L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(L.point(coords));
  return latLng;
 },
 onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
         layer.on({                    
                                    mouseover: function (e) {
                                        this.setStyle({
                                            'fillColor': 'yellow',
                                            'color': 'yellow'
                                            
                                        });
                                    },  
                                    mouseout: function (e) {
                                        this.setStyle({
                                            'fillColor': 'blue',
                                            'color': 'blue'
                                        });
                                    }       
                  });
                 }
             }).bindPopup(function (layer) {
          return layer.feature.properties.descriptio || 
         layer.feature.properties.description ;
        }).addTo(map);

        hybrid.addData(H23);
        hybrid.addData(H31);
        hybrid.addData(H49);
        hybrid.addData(H50);
        hybrid.addData(H67);
```

What should I do to make it running?

Occasionally I have also an error like this:

**Control.Layers.js:246 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setZIndex' of undefined**

all of these says nothing to me. Is anyone able to advise?

Comment: Hey MKR, At first glance, looks like you have a lot going on in there. I'm no expert, but I think the data needs to be loaded first. I moved the bottom 3 geojson bits to the top. Then it says things like can't find A23, etc. Where is the data for Annular, etc? Then looks like some typos, layer.feature.properties.descriptio, missing 'n'. I would start way simple with the example from github, get it running, then 1 by 1 add new features.

Comment: First try with standard Leaflet layer control `L.control.layers(maptiles, overlays).addTo(map);` and see if everything works. To make this control work, `overlays` must have standard Leaflet structure (same as `maptiles`), not the one for `L.control.groupedLayers`.

Comment: I've tried with the basic Leaflet Geojson example https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/ and it's still the same

Comment: This is then just question of debugging. Without having your code it's more or less impossible to find out what goes wrong. Your JSFiddle is missing data. Limit it to less data and include data in the code.

Comment: I've attached the full jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/okezw4dL/

Comment: only the with the first element is working when I set: L.control.layers(maptiles).addTo(map); nothing else unfortunately

Comment: This is not full working JSFiddle. All the data is missing (like 20240408.js and so on) and many libraries are also missing (like Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js, leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js and so on).

Comment: Ok, @TomazicM please inspect this website. It's my current stage of work:  http://eclipse.mkrgeo-blog.com/

Comment: But this is the working version, not the one that does not work. There are no overlays in the layer control.

Comment: Yes, because I have removed the issue. Let me upload it for you

Comment: I have uploaded the website

Comment: This is my last try: you are using grouped layer overlays syntax for creation of standard layers control, as I wrote in my second comment. Use normal Leaflet syntax, which has no groups.

Comment: Uploaded, still the same mate. I don't know where the problem is

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at `L.control.layers(maptiles, overlays).addTo(map);`, you'll see that `annular`, `hybrid` and `total` are all undefined at the time of the call. Here ends my debugging.

Comment: OK, so why are they undefinied? Should I move them somewhere beneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some simple JS debugging and understanding of JS logic needed to find out what and why it goes wrong.

When you get error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_leaflet_id' of undefined

at statement

```
var layers = L.control.groupedLayers(maptiles, overlays);
```

, you go to browser debugger, set a breakpoint at this statement and inspect values of `maptiles` and `overlays`. You'll notice that overlays `annular`, `hybrid` and `total` in `overlays` object are undefined at the time of statement execution. If you look at the code flow, that's logical, since object `overlays`, which uses those overlays, is defined before overlays are defined. This means that `overlays` definition and control creation should go after overlays definition.

When you do that, you'll notice that `places` overlay is not selected in the layer control, although layer itself is shown on the map. If you then try to select it, you'll get error:

> Uncaught Error: The provided object is not a Layer.

Reason for this is that `places` is not overlay but source GeoJSON object for the overlay. At the time of overlay creation, you have to assign it to some variable, let's say `placesOverlay` and then use this in `overlays` definition.

So code for places overlay should look something like this:

```
var placesLayer = L.geoJSON(places, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Code for overlays group and control creation should be put at the end and could look something like this:

```
var overlays = {
  "Eclipses" :{
    "Annular" : annular,
    "Hybrid" : hybrid,
    "Total" : total
  },
  "Places" : {
    "Places": placesLayer
  }
 };


var layers = L.control.groupedLayers(maptiles, overlays);
layers.addTo(map);
```

This is how the map looks like then (with limited set of data and without extra controls):

[image]